# Сравнение дат из базы данных sql

Tags: python, mysql

Мне нужно запустить цикл построчного сравнения дат.

Завтрашняя дата заносится в переменную в начале алгоритма и имеет вид в терминале: 2022-12-06

Вторая дата берется из столбца date_s (в таблице имеет тип данных date) и имеет вид: {'date_s': datetime.date(2022, 12, 6)}

При сравнении дат выдается ошибка: **'dict' object has no attribute 'day'**

Подскажите что я сделал не так. В sql заносил данные с помощью python, и какой бы способ вставки не пробовал - все равно вывод происходит через запятые, хотя в самом python используются "-"

```
    select = "SELECT date_s FROM client"
    cursor.execute(select)
    date_db = cursor.fetchall()
    for x in date_db:
        print(x)
        if tomorrow.day == x.day and tomorrow.month == x.month and tomorrow.year == x.year:
            print(1)
        else:
            print(0)
```

Comment: Вероятно, вместо x.day и т.д. нужно писать x["date_s"].day и т.д.

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо большое. Все заработало